# Mocha test order file-wise and webdriverjs instance persistence

Tags: javascript, webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm testing my web-app with Mocha and WebDriver. I'm struggling with the best practices regarding Mocha test-order and persistent state of the driver.

I want to separate tests to different files, e.g.

```
test\
    index.js
    selenium\
        login.js
        search.js
```

So in execution wise, login.js has to be first because it logs in to the app and gets authenticated. Only after that search.js is possible to do. But how? In login.js I now have this:

```
webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');

describe 'UI/Selenium', ->
    client = {}

    before ->
        client = webdriverjs.remote
            desiredCapabilities:
                browserName: 'chrome'

        client.init()
        client.windowHandleSize({width: 1920, height: 1080})

    it 'should let us login', (done) ->
        client.url('http://127.0.0.1:1337/login')
        .setValue('#username', 'username')
        .setValue('#password', 'password')
        .buttonClick('button[type="submit"]')
        .waitFor '#search_results_user', 5000, (err) -> throw err if err
        .call done
```

How can I persist the state of client to other tests without having to re-init it every time? And how do I define the execution order of files with Mocha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I persist the state of client to other tests without having to re-init it every time?

You setup whatever you want to share among tests in a `before` hook (and tear it down in an `after` hook). This would mean moving the code in your test for logging in into your `before` hook. Supposing you are testing the "foo" view, you could do:

```
describe("foo view", function () {
    before(function () { /* create selenium driver */ });

    describe("when used by a logged in user", function () {
        before(function () { /* log in */ });

        it(...

        it(...

        after(function () { /* log out */ });
    });

    describe("when used by a logged out user", function () {
        it(...

        it(...
    });
    after(function () { /* shut down the driver */ });
});
```

> And how do I define the execution order of files with Mocha?

**Mocha tests should not depend on one another and consequently should not depend on the order in which they are executed.**

If you are in a situation where you must break this cardinal rule, you could just invoke Mocha from the command line with the list of test files, in the order you want. Or you could launch Mocha programmatically and use [`addFile`](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically) to add the files in order.

Comment: There are a least two good reasons to want a certain order of test files. 1) You simply want the report to be in a particular order for human readers and 2) you might have tests for mocks (e.g. a mock API that intercepts real HTTP calls) that need to pass before it's safe for other tests to proceed, and mocks are precisely the kind of thing that other tests do depend on.